# c# Process.Start with credentials always "access is denied" when running in WPF application, Console is working fine

Tags: c#, .net, process, processstartinfo

I'm starting an external executable (provided as part of the project solution) to get the console output to analyze the result afterwards. All is working fine, when I use a Console application to start the process using Process.Start with the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = $"{location}find.exe"; // External EXE!
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{host}\" -printf \"%M %p\n\"";

// Set credentials
proc.StartInfo.Domain = domain;
proc.StartInfo.UserName = username;

System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
{
    ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
}
proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;

// StartInfo setup
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputErrorHandler);

proc.Start();  // <--- System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception occures on calling Start()
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

After adding the exact code to my WPF application it always throws an Exception saying "access is denied". Also while runnning the WPF application with Administrator rights the same error occures.

But it is working in WPF, if I take out the credentials, but then it is running under the local user, what should be avoided. Instead the given credentials should be used to start the process.

What is different with the WPF application? Am I missing anything?

Any hints appreciated...

NOTE EDIT:

I added a repo on github, which is also working as expected.
The included impersonation from codeproject is not working properly (in my case), but the Process.Start with credentials is now working fine in WPF...

Need to dig deeper in my current project...

Link to the Repo:
[CSharp-Impersonation-Example](https://github.com/SiL3NC3/CSharp-Impersonation-Example)

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: by calling the Start() function (comment added to the code example)

Comment: I found also a good article here: https://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/startprocessasuser

Comment: Are you an Admin?  VS does not enable Admin unless you start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: VS is always started with Administrator (in my case, because I'm also using local IIS for developing). Both CMD and WPF are run within the same project, so the situation is the same. Also with Admin the "access is denied" message comes up with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

There was some breaking change related to UseShellExecute which should be set to true when process is started from WPF - but then I am not sure that redirects are going to work (maybe also credentials)? Can you try to set it to true and give it try?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm getting -> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to start a process as a user.'

Comment: If you comment out Domain, UserName and Password - to run under current credential what is happening?

Comment: CMD is also running fine, but with the credentials of the local user. Without these settings also WPF is working fine...

Comment: Per MS:

The WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName and Password are provided. If the property is not set, the default working directory is %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.

So that could be the problem.

Comment: And find.exe exists in %SYSTEMROOT%\system32

Comment: Still "access is denied" also with a working directory set. I'm providing a full path for calling the exe... (which is not the find.exe from Windows) with an executable as part the project.